# Should unit tests bypass external applications?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, vim, command-line

I'm working on a pet project that opens a text editor. (In my case, vim.) How should I unit test an app like this? Is the answer to just bypass this line of code whenever it's running in the test env?

For reference, here's the line that calls vim in my project: https://github.com/lorentrogers/jekylljournal/blob/open-today/bin/jekylljournal#L22

Comment: In this case you would probably want to mock it out and test all of the different results of activating the editor such as return codes and different file outputs.

Comment: Makes sense - where should I look to do this? I'm vaguely familiar with Mocha: https://github.com/freerange/mocha Would this be the right approach?

Comment: And, any idea how this would integrate with Cucumber/Aruba?